# Videos in photoLibrary for imagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to show videos tile only in my imagePickerController. I understand that you have to change the mediaType and I already did that. All I want is for it to show only videos tile, not camera roll and moments like you see here

[image]

I only want the one videos tile as seen in this picture. I don't want to have to click into camera roll and then see video. I just want a seperate video tile that makes it clear that only videos are in there.

[image]

I have added the controller for my image picker

```
/// Selector Controller used to pick an image
open class ImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController, TypedRowControllerType, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    /// The row that pushed or presented this controller
    public var row: RowOf<URL>!

    /// A closure to be called when the controller disappears.
    public var onDismissCallback : ((UIViewController) -> ())?

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        allowsEditing = (row as? _VideoRow)?.allowEditor ?? false
        mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeVideo as String]

    }


    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL else {
            return
        }

        (row as? _VideoRow)?.videoURL = videoURL
        (row as? _VideoRow)?.value = videoURL
        onDismissCallback?(self)
    }

    open func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
        onDismissCallback?(self)
    }

    private func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationItem.title = "Videos"
    }

}
```

Also why can I not change the title

Answer (score 0):

> All I want is for it to show only videos tile, not camera roll and moments like you see here

Then don't use UIImagePickerController; write your own picker. If you use UIImagePickerController, you are limited to what it gives you. It gives you source types `.photoLibrary` and `.savedPhotosAlbum` and that's all.

Comment: can you point me in the direction of where I could learn that?

Comment: Privately, I could probably do a search for you, but why not do the search yourself now that you know what the problem is going to be? Stack Overflow is not a place ask for a tutorial or other online resource. You asked how to customize UIImagePickerController in a certain way, and I answered you, telling you that you can't do it.

Comment: I already tried to do the search and im not getting much thats why I asked

Comment: Really? https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=UIImagePickerController+replacement

Comment: on most libraries all they do is this  imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeMovie as String] to make the videos tile appear but with mines it isn't

Comment: Well it would be silly to include `kUTTypeImage` if you only want videos, wouldn't it? But in any case that's not the point.

Comment: Yeah i get that but all im saying is in this tutorial he added that one line and the videos tile magically appeared
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRkpdRDYGeM

Comment: but it wont in mines